# How to compile and run a F# script in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

I can compile the demo script `hello.fsx`
Listed Below:

```
open System
[<EntryPoint>]
let main (param: string[]) =
    printf "Hello %s\n" param.[0]
    0
```

with:

```
fsc hello.fsx
```

and then run it with:

```
.\hello.exe Bill
```

This works fine. My question is whether or not it is possible to accomplish these steps within Visual Studio, in an automated, implicit manner?

Comment: Why do you have `main` in a `.fsx` file?  That is not quite right

Comment: @JohnPalmer Actually, I'm following the examples in a F# book (Functional Programming Using F#, by Hansen & Richel).

Comment: Are you sure it isn't meant to be a `.fs` file - it would be more normal to see `main` there

Comment: @JohnPalmer Yes. To quote from the book: " The program source file Hello.fsx compiles to an exe-file using the F# batch compiler:
fsc Hello.fsx -o Hello.exe
and the program can now be called from a command prompt..."

Comment: I guess it is valid code but probably non-idiomatic (normally `.fsx` is used for scripts - see documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx)

Comment: @JohnPalmer Yes, I'm doing with script. See my question title: _How to compile and run a **F# script** in Visual Studio?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what do you mean by "these steps".

If you want to create executable in Visual Studio you can create a new project of type "Console Application".

If you want to test your main function in F# interactive window, comment out `[<EntryPoint>]` attribute and call function main directly.

```
open System
let main (param: string[]) =
    printf "Hello %s\n" param.[0]
    0

main [|"Bill"|]
```

Select the code you want to execute and hit `Alt-Enter` and results of execution will be shown in F# interactive window.

Comment: Thank you! It's good to know how to pass command argument in F# Interactive.

Comment: I think this does not answer the question, how to run a F# script in Visual Studio. There does not seem to be a way to even debug a F# script in Visual Studio, unless one is willing to convert it to a project, which includes whole lot of crap files.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you would like the IDE to pass in command-line arguments when you execute your with 'Start Debugging' or 'Start Without Debugging', then you merely need to open your project properties, go to the 'Debug' panel, and add the arguments to the 'Command line arguments' textbox. The documentation for this can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wcdezs5.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the documentation. There's a lot to learn for the rookie programmer. I'll keep reading.